Path Problems with Brackets in GIT subtree pull
My Problem is i can add a subtree like this:
git subtree add --prefix=resources/[standalone]/PolyZone polyzone master --squash
But i can not pull like this:
git subtree pull --prefix=resources/[standalone]/PolyZone polyzone master --squash
if i pull like that it told me
"fatal: can't squash-merge: 'resources/[standalone]/PolyZone' was never added."
I figured out thats because the brackets in "[standalone]" and i tried to escape them with backslashes or double backslashes or \Q or \E or using ' ' or " " but i can not pull with that path. Why can i add a subtree to this path but i can not pull it with that path, i need that brackets in that directory names?
i tried to escape them with backslashes or double backslashes or \Q or \E or using ' ' or " " but i can not pull with that path. Why can i add a subtree to this path but i can not pull it with that path, i need that brackets in that directory names?
